# Is there a way to prevent `g++` from consolidating exit points for a function at O3?

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, abort

Consider the following program, which I will put in a file called `Lie.cc`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void foo(int argc) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        abort();
    }
    if (argc == 4) {
        printf("Hello World\n");
        abort();
    }
}
int main(int argc, const char** argv){
    foo(argc);
}
```

I am running `gcc version 5.4.0` and I compile this program as follows.

```
g++  -std=c++11 -fPIC -O3 -g -lpthread -o Lie Lie.cc
```

If I run this under `gdb` and pass in a single argument, I get the following backtrace.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7a43428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007ffff7a4502a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00000000004005db in foo (argc=<optimized out>) at Lie.cc:11
#3  0x00000000004004a9 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at Lie.cc:15
```

It seems that `gdb` believes we took the abort on line 11 instead of the abort on line 7. The assembly dump of `foo` reveals that `gdb` has no way of differentiating, and is simple **guessing**.

```
objdump -d Lie > Lie.asm

  00000000004005b0 <_Z3fooi>:
  4005b0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4005b4:   83 ff 02                cmp    $0x2,%edi
  4005b7:   74 1d                   je     4005d6 <_Z3fooi+0x26>
  4005b9:   83 ff 04                cmp    $0x4,%edi
  4005bc:   74 05                   je     4005c3 <_Z3fooi+0x13>
  4005be:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  4005c2:   c3                      retq···
  4005c3:   48 8d 35 9a 00 00 00    lea    0x9a(%rip),%rsi        # 400664 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
  4005ca:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  4005cf:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4005d1:   e8 aa fe ff ff          callq  400480 <__printf_chk@plt>
  4005d6:   e8 85 fe ff ff          callq  400460 <abort@plt>
  4005db:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

Is it possible to prevent `gcc` from consolidating the two calls to `abort()` and making them indistinguishable?

Comment: Something tells me you won't accept "don't use `-O3` for debugging" as an answer...?

Comment: @KerrekSB, Bug is a race condition that does not reproduce under `-O0`. Also, [this problem](http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2009/11/16/why-did-my-breakpoint-not-get-hit/) is not unique to `-O3`.

Comment: What about `-Og` then? Or TSAN?

Comment: @KerrekSB, `-Og` leads to hallucinated warnings. I hadn't heard of TSAN, but I'm looking into it now.

Comment: I don't know how to prevent g++ from consolidating your exit points, but you could identify which path was taken to reach abort by using reverse-debugging. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @cgmb, The last time I tried that feature in gdb, it claimed that I was using instructions unsupported by reverse debugging. There seem to be floating point restrictions and it does not support the full subset of x86_64 instructions.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but good to know. I haven't used it much myself, but it worked beautifully for the example above so I had high hopes.

Comment: Does it reproduce under `-Og` (optimize without disturbing debuggability)?

Comment: Does `-fno-crossjumping` do what you want?

Comment: @ephemient, Yes, it reproduces under `-Og`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, That option has had no effect on the example.

Comment: Oh well, it produced distinct calls to abort on godbolt. I'll look at it some more when I'm at a terminal.

Comment: FWIW, with `-fno-crossjumping` I get "correct" result from the test program using `7.0.0 20170116 (experimental)` and `Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3` GCC. It's possible that this was temporarily broken for version `5.4.0`.

Comment: Oh, and I also get correct output with `-Og`.